# How to test XML De-/Serialization

Tags: c#, xunit

So I tried to create a very simple **XmlFileWriter**

```
public class XmlFileWriter
{
    public void WriteTo<TSerializationData>(string path, TSerializationData data)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TSerializationData));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, data);
        }
    }
}
```

and **XmlFileReader**

```
public class XmlFileReader
{
    public TSerializationData ReadFrom<TSerializationData>(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TSerializationData));

            return (TSerializationData) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create unit tests for both of them with **xUnit**. Since they are coupled to the filesystem I was looking for a way to mock it somehow. Many Posts highly recommend the **System.IO.Abstractions** package and the additional **TestingHelpers**.

I will only show the tests for the reader for now since both scenarios are very similiar. This is what I have so far

```
[Fact]
public void ThrowsExceptionIfPathIsInvalid()
{
    XmlFileReader xmlFileReader = new XmlFileReader();

    // use an empty path since it should be invalid
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => xmlFileReader.ReadFrom<object>(string.Empty));
}

[Fact]
public void DeserializesDataFromXmlFile()
{
    // Generate dummy data with default values
    MyDummyClass dummyData = new MyDummyClass();
    XmlFileWriter xmlFileWriter = new XmlFileWriter();
    XmlFileReader xmlFileReader = new XmlFileReader();
    string filePath = "???"; // TODO

    // Generate a new file and use it as a mock file
    xmlFileWriter.WriteTo(filePath, dummyData);

    // Read from that file
    MyDummyClass fileContent = xmlFileReader.ReadFrom<MyDummyClass>(filePath);

    // Compare the result
    Assert.Equal(dummyData, fileContent);
}
```

I'm struggling with decoupling the real Filesystem. How would I make the `XmlSerializer` class use a fake filesystem? I installed the abstractions package but I don't know how to use it for this case (for reading and writing).

Comment: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` both have constructors that accept a [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1). I recommend making your method also take streams as parameters, and the your unit tests can supply a `MemoryStream` containing your test xml as a string (which can be hardcoded), while your actual application can provide a `FileStream` that is the file on disk

Comment: ahh so the `XmlSerializer` is not the problem?

Comment: Both your classes are useless. They don't add anything new to the XmlSerializer functionality. Use the XmlSerializer directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) and [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) both have constructors that accept a Stream. I recommend making your method also take streams as parameters, and the your unit tests can supply a [`MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netcore-3.1) containing your test xml as a string (which can be hardcoded), while your actual application can provide a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netcore-3.1) that is the file on disk. Like so:

```cs
public void WriteTo<TSerializationData>(Stream location, TSerializationData data)
{
    // Code here doesn't change
}

public TSerializationData ReadFrom<TSerializationData>(Stream location)
{
    // Code here doesn't change
}
```

Then in your tests you can do:

```cs
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sr = new StreamWriter())
    {
        sr.Write("<xml>This is your dummy XML string, can be anything you want</xml>");
    }

    MyDummyClass fileContent = xmlFileReader.ReadFrom<MyDummyClass>(ms);
}
```

And if you want to read from a file you can do:

```cs
// Using whatever FileMode/ FileAccess you need
MyDummyClass fileContent;
using (var fs = File.Open(@"C:\Path\To\File.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    fileContent = xmlFileReader.ReadFrom<MyDummyClass>(fs);
}
```